# Installing Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c on 11gR2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, oracle-enterprise-manager

Installing Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c

The progress just halts at 52% with this message

```
Configuration assistant "Repository Configuration" is in progress log file shows.

oracle.sysman.top.oms still running...
```

Comment: Are you installing on Windows? Is the DB on the same host?

Comment: What versions of RDBMS and OEM are involved?

Comment: i am doing this on linux  - Nikita

Comment: RDMBS is 11.2.0.4  , and OEM 12c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to be patient and give installation more time to complete. It seems that your hardware specs are low that's why Installation is taking more time than usual.

Answer (score 0):

you should run in instractions in SQL/plus:(these get afew time)

```
DROP USER SYSMAN CASCADE; 
DROP USER SYSMAN_OPSS CASCADE;
DROP USER SYSMAN_MDS CASCADE;
DROP USER SYSMAN_APM CASCADE;
DROP USER SYSMAN_RO CASCADE;


DECLARE
  CURSOR l_syn_csr IS
    SELECT 'DROP ' ||
      CASE owner
        WHEN 'PUBLIC'
          THEN 'PUBLIC SYNONYM '
        ELSE 'SYNONYM ' || owner || '.'
      END ||
      synonym_name AS cmd
    FROM
  dba_synonyms 
WHERE
  table_owner IN (
    'SYSMAN',
    'SYSMAN_MDS',
    'MGMT_VIEW',
    'SYSMAN_BIP',
    'SYSMAN_APM',
    'BIP',
    'SYSMAN_OPSS',
    'SYSMAN_RO'
  );
BEGIN
  FOR l_syn_rec IN l_syn_csr LOOP
    BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_syn_rec.cmd;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( '===> ' || l_syn_rec.cmd );
    dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm );
END;
END LOOP;
 END;
/



DROP USER mgmt_view CASCADE;
DROP TABLESPACE mgmt_ecm_depot_ts INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES CASCADE 
CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLESPACE mgmt_tablespace   INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES CASCADE 
CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLESPACE mgmt_ad4j_ts      INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES CASCADE 
CONSTRAINTS;

DELETE
  FROM
    schema_version_registry
  WHERE
(comp_name,owner) IN (
  ('Authorization Policy Manager','SYSMAN_APM'),
  ('Metadata Services','SYSMAN_MDS'),
  ('Oracle Platform Security Services','SYSMAN_OPSS')
);
 commit;
```